# Can not create the AVD in eclipse+adt bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

[Also, I don't have an android device manager with my ADT bundle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LZyc.png)
[The OK button is disabled and I could not create any AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD7zI.png)

Please suggest what can be done either I have to download a new adt-bundle or anything can be done in current scenario?

Comment: which version ADT you used ???

Comment: "20140702" I guess the final version.

Comment: I mean 22.6 or other ?

Comment: The ADT and Eclipse tooling is long since deprecated.  You should seriously consider switching to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ok button disabled issue,  you had not installed the system images under

$YOUR_SDK_INSTALLATION_DIR/system-images/

which are required for emulation and related configurations,
hope it helps.